# How to iterate through all the loaded dlls in a process without opening a handle

Tags: c++

I know how you would get a list of dlls that are loaded in a process with a handle but I would like to avoid creating any type of handle to the process so I cannot use EnumProcessModules. I tried going through parsing the PE header but I failed.

Comment: Sounds like you wish to recreate [Dependency Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker). A worthwhile goal. See if you can steal ideas from the open source projects at the Wikipedia link.

Comment: The PE header will tell you to which DLLs the executable is linked. However, this will only mention DLLs that it linked to at compile-time, but it is possible to link to additional DLLs at run-time, for example using the function [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya). These DLLs will not be visible in the PE header.

Comment: There are a number of libraries out there to help parse PE file headers. Once you have one, you'll want to look in the Import Directory area.

Comment: If you want to also see all DLLs that an executable has linked to using `LoadLibrary`, then you may want to read [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-module-list).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel that requires creating handles, which the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @ManLing what is wrong with opening a handle to a process to use `EnumProcessModules()` on it? Why are you forcing this artificial restriction on yourself?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: OP stated that they don't want to create "any type of handle to the process". In contrast to the function `EnumProcessModules`, the function `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` does not require a handle to the process; it only requires a process ID. That function creates a handle to the snapshot, but not to the process itself. Therefore, I believe that this complies with the restrictions stated by OP (unless the function `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` internally creates a handle to the process, that is uses internally).